# Wrong unicode glyphs in emacs?

Tags: character-encoding, unicode

I recently came across a python file "*.py" containing several prints consisting of unicode symbols. I noticed that several symbols are
displayed with different glyphs in emacs than in another editor.
Specifically, the glyphs in emacs seem to be wrong, i.e. not
the ones intended to be displayed. The file is encoded in
utf-8 (as is allowed in case of python files).

One specific case is the symbol Δ (capital Greek Delta, `\u0394`).
I typed `list-charset-chars`, followed by `unicode-bmp`. The
corresponding table is the following:

```
    0   1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9   A   B   C   D   E   F
30x ̀   ́   ̂   ̃   ̄   ̅   ̆   ̇   ̈   ̉   ̊   ̋   ̌   ̍   ̎   ̏
31x ̐   ̑   ̒   ̓   ̔   ̕   ̖   ̗   ̘   ̙   ̚   ̛   ̜   ̝   ̞   ̟
32x ̠   ̡   ̢   ̣   ̤   ̥   ̦   ̧   ̨   ̩   ̪   ̫   ̬   ̭   ̮   ̯
33x ̰   ̱   ̲   ̳   ̴   ̵   ̶   ̷   ̸   ̹   ̺   ̻   ̼   ̽   ̾   ̿
34x ̀   ́   ͂   ̓   ̈́   ͅ   ͆   ͇   ͈   ͉   ͊   ͋   ͌   ͍   ͎   ͏
35x ͐   ͑   ͒   ͓   ͔   ͕   ͖   ͗   ͘   ͙   ͚   ͛   ͜   ͝   ͞   ͟
36x ͠   ͡   ͢   ͣ   ͤ   ͥ   ͦ   ͧ   ͨ   ͩ   ͪ   ͫ   ͬ   ͭ   ͮ   ͯ
37x Ͱ   ͱ   Ͳ   ͳ   ʹ   ͵   Ͷ   ͷ   ͸   ͹   ͺ   ͻ   ͼ   ͽ   ;   Ϳ
38x ΀   ΁   ΂   ΃   ΄   ΅   Ά   ·   Έ   Ή   Ί   ΋   Ό   ΍   Ύ   Ώ
39x ΐ   Α   Β   Γ   Δ   Ε   Ζ   Η   Θ   Ι   Κ   Λ   Μ   Ν   Ξ   Ο
3Ax Π   Ρ   ΢   Σ   Τ   Υ   Φ   Χ   Ψ   Ω   Ϊ   Ϋ   ά   έ   ή   ί
3Bx ΰ   α   β   γ   δ   ε   ζ   η   θ   ι   κ   λ   μ   ν   ξ   ο
3Cx π   ρ   ς   σ   τ   υ   φ   χ   ψ   ω   ϊ   ϋ   ό   ύ   ώ   Ϗ
3Dx ϐ   ϑ   ϒ   ϓ   ϔ   ϕ   ϖ   ϗ   Ϙ   ϙ   Ϛ   ϛ   Ϝ   ϝ   Ϟ   ϟ
3Ex Ϡ   ϡ   Ϣ   ϣ   Ϥ   ϥ   Ϧ   ϧ   Ϩ   ϩ   Ϫ   ϫ   Ϭ   ϭ   Ϯ   ϯ
3Fx ϰ   ϱ   ϲ   ϳ   ϴ   ϵ   ϶   Ϸ   ϸ   Ϲ   Ϻ   ϻ   ϼ   Ͻ   Ͼ   Ͽ
```

This seems correct, however, the situation looks differently in emacs:

[image: emacs character sets]

Specifically, the Delta is replaced by a strange-looking glyph instead.

I reproduced this using `emacs -q`, so it is not my specific dotemacs
causing this problem (although it could be another part of my setup,
such as the installed fonts).

Q: What am I doing wrong, how can I fix the behavior?

Comment: Have you tried setting different default fonts - `menu-set-font`?